# Diffrent output of "ps -a" on Ubuntu and Fedora

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, ps

I have noticed that the `ps -a` command produces different output when I run it on ubuntu "16.04" and Fedora 23. According the man page of both distribution the -a option should do :

> -a Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal.

This doesn't seem to be the case for Ubuntu.

- Ubuntu output : [Pastbin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16591469/)
- Fedora output : [Pastbin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16591533/)

I am unable to explain this behavior as it seems that they have the same version of procps.

Fedora:

- Name    : procps-ng
- version : 3.3.10

Ubuntu:

- Package : procps
- Version : 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2

Have you any idea why this is happening ? Am I doing some thing wrong ?

Thanks,
BR,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps` man page

> -a     Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal.

This behavior is explained by the fact that there is more processes attached to a terminal in Fedora compared to Ubuntu.

1. [Ubuntu](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16643114/)
2. [Fedora](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16643126/)

Answer (score 2):

There are, at least, two things this could be. The most likely is that `ps` is aliased to `ps -A` (or `ps a`; the a without the - results in behavior similar to -A) on fedora; which would explain the output format.
On each system type `which ps` which will reveal what aliases if any are being called instead of the executable directly.

You can bypass any aliases by either either calling the full path of the program (e.g. `/bin/ps` or by starting the command with a leading '\', e.g. `\ps`.

The far less likely thing is that the two distros compiled ps with different flags (resulting in different behavior). I just checked ps on fedora 23, and it's default output is the same as what you are getting from ubunutu, so I think you have an alias set.

The alias is most likely set in the file ~/.bashrc; although other locations are possible. You can see the aliases in your current environment by typing `alias` with no arguments in the terminal.

### Update:

Since they aren't aliased, something else (to state the obvious) is modifying the behavior. Here are a few things to look at to find out what that is:
On each system, run them in a 'clean' environment:

```
env -i ps
```

and see if the behavior changes. If it does, then we know it's an enviromental setting changing it.

on each system, enter the following command:
`ps --info`

See if the field `personality=0x` field is non zero which can change the output. Note any other differences from that output; post them if you can't decode the meaning of the difference.

To see if something is re-purposing `ps`, run the following in the bash shell on each:

```
set -x
ps -a
```

You should see something like:

```
+ps -a
```

echoed out; if you see something else, e.g. `+ps aux`, then that would cause this. That is usually done by an alias but it could be a function.
You can turn off the bash spam by running `set +x`

On each machine check if the binary is an symlink to something else and if there is something odd going on there (likely on fedora that /usr/bin/ps is a sym link to /bin/ps)

```
ls -alt /bin/ps
ls -alt /usr/bin/ps
```

Try

```
type ps
```

On each machine; the results should be the same, if not respond with the results.

There are some enviromental variables that can modify the behavior of ps; to see these type `man ps`; they are at the bottom. type `env` on each OS and see if any are set; you can grep for them:

```
env | grep 'CMD_ENV\|PS_PERSONALITY\|_XPG'
```

There are others; see the manpage to add them to the query if these return nothing or to figure what the setting means to `ps`.

Getting into the weeds here, but if you still have nothing, check the binary file headers on each:

```
readelf -h /bin/ps
```

If none of that shows any differences, you can copy the /bin/ps file to the other OS and do a compare:

```
cmp -b /bin/ps /path/to/copy/of/ps
```

That will output all of the bytes that differ between the two files. The actual values don't matter; just the number of differences.

They will be different; if it's only a couple bytes difference than that would just be the gcc field NT_GNU_BUILD_ID which is unique for every build, even otherwise identical files. If they are not substantially different than it's an environmentally influenced behavior, and I can't think of anymore to check.

Comment: There is no alias for ps on both distribution, \ps produces the same result.

Comment: and the command `which ps` gave you the same results on both? I updated the answer with some additional things to look at.

Comment: The output of "which ps" is "/usr/bin/ps" on fedora and "/bin/ps" on ubuntu. I have also grep the output of the "alias" command and "ps" is not in.

Comment: The Fedora version of `ps` behaved as the Ubuntu version when run on Ubuntu. Could it be related to kernel version (4.4.0 on Ubuntu and 4.4.9 on Fedora) ?

Comment: Did you try the other steps? env -i ?  What were those results?

Comment: Yes all other steps didn't change the behavior of ps (except for cmp which I didn't test)

Comment: Based on what you've described it has to be an environmental config. I would think one of those tests I listed would indicate or at least hint at one. The odds of ps --info producing identical results are exceedingly low, with a different distros build system. What version of ubuntu?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04. ps --info is not the same gcc, glibc and kernel are different

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have learned some stuff from your answer.